# Can someone explain like I'm five how this counts how many letters are in a string without repeating?

Tags: javascript, string

I know what the code does, but I still don't understand it so I can repeat it myself. If anyone can help, that would be great!

```
function strLetterCount(string) {
  const characters = {};
  let str = "";

  for (let character of string) {
    characters[character] = characters[character] + 1 || 1;
  }
  for (let key in characters) {
    str += `${key}${characters[key]}`
  }
  console.log(str);
  return str;
}


strLetterCount("taco"); // "t1a1c1o1"
strLetterCount("coconut"); // "c2o2n1u1t1"
```

Comment: What is a debugger?

Comment: You should go through it line by line, writing down on paper what each step does and how the state of each variable changes with each step. Is there any particular operation that you don’t understand? Then you have a detailed question to research or ask about.

Comment: It doesn't seem to do the work without repeating, there are two iteration loops in the code.

Comment: @Teemu Huh? One for counting, one for building the result. Not sure what your point is.

Comment: @deceze Maybe I misunderstood the title, but to me it says "_[how the code works] without repeating_"?

Comment: @Teemu Without repeating the letters, I’d assume.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So if you follow the `console.log` in the below snippet, you'll be able to understand the working of the code. What it does is this:

There is an empty object `characters={}` which holds each character of the string as its key by iterating the string. At each iteration, if the key is not there, the object is assigned the key (which is `character` of `string`) and value is assigned as 1. If this key is already there, its value is simply increased. Finally all the `key-value` pair from this object is joined together and returned.

```js
function strLetterCount(string) {
  const characters = {};
  let str = "";

  for (let character of string) {
   console.log(character)
    characters[character] = characters[character] + 1 || 1;
   console.log(characters)
  }
  for (let key in characters) {
    str += `${key}${characters[key]}`
  }
  console.log(str);
  return str;
}


strLetterCount("taco"); // "t1a1c1o1"
strLetterCount("coconut"); // "c2o2n1u1t1"
```

Comment: Ohhh! I was confused with "characters[character] = characters[character] + 1 || 1;". How you explained it totally made sense to me though. It's either set to characters[character] + 1 OR set to 1. I think I was trying to combine it like in an or statement, if that makes sense.

Comment: Yeah that's right, if `characters[key]` is not present it will be set to 1 or else, the value will be simply increased by 1.

Comment: OR (||) works like this:  `var b = a|| 1` if `a` has a *truthy* value (not `undefined, null, ` etc) then b will be assigned the value of a (it won't go for checking 1 in that case) else it will go and check the second parameter after `||` if that has a `truthy` value

Answer (score 0):

It creates an object ‘characters’ to keep a count of occurrences per character; then loops through the input string character by character, incrementing the corresponding counter in the ‘characters’ object each time.

The ‘characters’ object looks like this:

```
characters = {
  “a”: 11,
  “b”: 4,
  “d”: 2,
  ...
}
```

Finally it goes through this object key by key and adds up the counts.

Answer (score 0):

Let's imagine that you're 15 - then this should be enough :)

```js
// you pass your string here
function strLetterCount(string) {
  // this is object that will store letters and counts, like this:
  // { "a": 1, "b": 3, "c": 2, ... }
  const characters = {};
  // this will be resulting string, like "a1b3c2"
  let str = "";

  // for each letter of `string`, put it in variable `character`
  for (let character of string) {
    // if `characters` object already has current letter - increase count by one
    // otherwise - initialize it with 1
    characters[character] = characters[character] + 1 || 1;
  }

  // for each letter in `characters` object
  for (let key in characters) {
    // add to resulting `str` letter followed by the number of occurrences 
    str += `${key}${characters[key]}`
  }
  // output result in console
  console.log(str);
  // return result
  return str;
}


strLetterCount("taco"); // "t1a1c1o1"
strLetterCount("coconut"); // "c2o2n1u1t1"
```

Answer (score 0):

> **Q** : *"Can someone explain like I'm five **how this counts** how many letters are in a string without repeating?"*

Sure, with pleasure - let's run it step by step [in an interactive IDE](https://tio.run/##vVTRbhoxEHznK1anSIAIpdA2rQ5ChCiVTkpJlfBWRYpjDFw5bGT7IIjw7XRsKDkgUtOHYml1ts@znh3v7i82Y4breGrLUvXFej1IJbexkmSsvhbWCt1WqbQFt47lkIq0pMyoVOhH67b1vdPr3GLZ2JxqUiHqFnNEXEljiY@YZhyuDF3SclWn1wd8Rd2oF7Wuo7vOV2q8wJpwlQjrOMBD0L7p9lpR9y6koP42VwA2c5VK@b8OkBwoTQXHdMed1GAr3YFyniQ1YpxhVjRJzXBYMD7aiZg3GQ2cBJRR8udueg9JXt8vUZWen6laB3ZF/zAcs@hb9nZiiRasv0CEqexTLPeeh0rVcmzPHaZ70ztHwEoLXB7YkdAiOKnyY7Fw9F7YHem@p7zSe9ID3TyMzivvUq90SQ9nSxxZhWfLjOTYuV/RQ9Z7ZrDpVEAy7zokhimTuMKKIW7lrrg2evWpn/oS2xWR4UxKt8MeQfGAlr/VcVudQl5XyCoR7xI1LIBesf639DEjNSc8PzFjxOQxQXi@CgmtZesMbrWwqfa9pv62rNwCNgV9gsgPumBgGVfBJnrQyXQiG1aJwThMwYIjKFeIO7UOvQ/lYQ2QGknAUpj18CN8G2lj1EQoKUg8TROGfEjisaAoP6FBjATZSB6bTVYZv54wuXC903dfpn0WsT/NfB7bkUotVJ0KZrFzBXa5g/w9eIIM8baP@QLEvxCF1c9kwk@I5IIm4QcSYfU9PeHEFKEl2Ihxaox1BMvDBrAZbBR@pDn@W/znXoIaLfDV2B9ifuXlWK9/Aw)

The trick with a hidden surprise is in the first `for(){...}`-block :

```
function strLetterCount( string ) {            // PARAMETER   <string> (IN)
  const characters = {};                       // INITIALISED <characters>
  let str = "CONTAINS: ";                      // INITIALISED <str>
//----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  for (let character of string) {              //  <iterate> over each <string>'s <character>
    characters[character] = characters[character] + 1 || 1;
  }                                            //     IF <character> already found in <characters> +1-it, IF NOT, store 1 "there"
//----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  for (let key in characters) {                //  <iterator> over each <key> in <characters>
    str += `${key}:${characters[key]} `        //             append <key>: and an integer count stored during <string> scanning above in <characters[key]>
  }
//----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  console.log(str);                            //  show the assembled <str> on console
  return str;                                  //  return <str>
}
//----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
strLetterCount("taco");    // "CONTAINS: t:1 a:1 c:1 o:1 "
strLetterCount("coconut"); // "CONTAINS: c:2 o:2 n:1 u:1 t:1 "

strLetterCount("Can someone explain like I'm five how this counts how many letters are in a string without repeating?");
//                         // "CONTAINS: C:1 a:6 n:8  :17 s:5 o:6 m:3 e:10 x:1 p:2 l:3 i:8 k:1 I:1 ':1 f:1 v:1 h:4 w:3 t:8 c:1 u:2 y:1 r:4 g:2 ?:1 "
```